# I'm struggling with the coarray implementation in Intel Fortran Compiler (IFX) 2024 and Visual Studio 17 (Windows 11):

Tags: intel-fortran, intel-oneapi

The code is the simple code available in One API documentation for the test of the coarray functionality (reported below). The build of target "coarray2.exe" completes correctly (see image)  but execution ends with an error code  1090191.

[output of the compiler and error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSRbp.png)

I did the initialisation of oneAPI with the setvars.bat command in the compiler directory that for me is C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\2024.0\bin. The same path was added in the manually in the environment variable PATH.

I also add here a screen-shot of the compiler options:

[compiler options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbsYG.png)

```
! ==============================================================
! Copyright © 2020 Intel Corporation
!
! SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
! =============================================================
!
! Part of the Coarray Tutorial. For information, please read
! Tutorial: Using Fortran Coarrays
! Getting Started Tutorials document

program mcpi

! This program demonstrates using Fortran coarrays to implement the classic
! method of computing the mathematical value pi using a Monte Carlo technique.
!
! Compiler options: /Qcoarray
!                   -coarray 
!

implicit none

! Declare kind values for large integers, single and double precision
integer, parameter :: K_BIGINT = selected_int_kind(15)
integer, parameter :: K_DOUBLE = selected_real_kind(15,300)

! Number of trials per image. The bigger this is, the better the result
! This value must be evenly divisible by the number of images.
integer(K_BIGINT), parameter :: num_trials = 600000000_K_BIGINT

! Actual value of PI to 18 digits for comparison
real(K_DOUBLE), parameter :: actual_pi = 3.141592653589793238_K_DOUBLE

! Declare scalar coarray that will exist on each image
 integer(K_BIGINT) :: total[*] ! Per-image subtotal

! Local variables
real(K_DOUBLE) :: x,y
real(K_DOUBLE) :: computed_pi
integer :: i
integer(K_BIGINT) :: bigi
integer(K_BIGINT) :: clock_start,clock_end,clock_rate
integer, allocatable :: seed_array(:)
integer :: seed_size

! Image 1 initialization
if (THIS_IMAGE() == 1) then
    ! Make sure that num_trials is divisible by the number of images
    if (MOD(num_trials,INT(NUM_IMAGES(),K_BIGINT)) /= 0_K_BIGINT) &
        error stop "Number of trials not evenly divisible by number of images!"
    print '(A,I0,A,I0,A)', "Computing pi using ",num_trials," trials across ",NUM_IMAGES()," images"
    call SYSTEM_CLOCK(clock_start)
end if

! Set the initial random number seed to an unpredictable value, with a different
! sequence on each image. 
call RANDOM_INIT(.FALSE.,.TRUE.) 

! Initialize our subtotal
total = 0_K_BIGINT

! Run the trials, with each image doing its share of the trials.
!
! Get a random X and Y and see if the position is within a circle of radius 1. 
! If it is, add one to the subtotal
do bigi=1_K_BIGINT,num_trials/int(NUM_IMAGES(),K_BIGINT)
    call RANDOM_NUMBER(x)
    call RANDOM_NUMBER(y)
    if ((x*x)+(y*y) <= 1.0_K_DOUBLE) total = total + 1_K_BIGINT
end do

! Wait for everyone
sync all

! Image 1 end processing
if (this_image() == 1) then
    ! Sum subtotals of all images
    do i=2,num_images()
        total = total + total[i]
    end do

    ! total/num_trials is an approximation of pi/4
    computed_pi = 4.0_K_DOUBLE*(REAL(total,K_DOUBLE)/REAL(num_trials,K_DOUBLE))
    print '(A,G0.8,A,G0.3)', "Computed value of pi is ", computed_pi, &
        ", Relative Error: ",ABS((computed_pi-actual_pi)/actual_pi)
    ! Show elapsed time
    call SYSTEM_CLOCK(clock_end,clock_rate)
    print '(A,G0.3,A)', "Elapsed time is ", &
        REAL(clock_end-clock_start)/REAL(clock_rate)," seconds"
end if
    
end program mcpi
```

Comment: Please never put error output into pictures. Copy and paste it into your question **as text**. This is very important. Especially the error messages must be searcheable. The error code is almost useless, we need the full error output in the question itself as text. See [ask].

Comment: Thanks for feedback, the text is following:

The thread 18948 has exited with code 1090191 (0x10a28f).
The thread 18904 has exited with code 1090191 (0x10a28f).
The thread 18960 has exited with code 1090191 (0x10a28f).
The program '[10004] coarray02.exe' has exited with code 1090191 (0x10a28f).

Comment: Use [edit] to put the error info into the question, comments may be deleted any time.

Comment: Consider also that the inizialisation was correctly executed with command setvars.bat and (result was: SETVARS_COMPLETED=1) and environmet variable PATH is set to  C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\2024.0\bin.

Comment: Which Debugging options are enabled?

Comment: In Language tab:
-Use file extensions
-132 columns
-Enable alternate PARAMETER syntax
-Generate parallel code (/Qopenmp)
-Generate Parallel Code (/Qiopenmp)
-Enable coarray: for shared memory (/Qcoarray:shared)
Coarray Images:6

Comment: I solved the issue: after carefull re-installation of Visual Studio 2022 with C++ tools and re-installation of oneAPI Base Kit + HPC Toolkit, the environment variable were porperly set.